# Erro ao abrir link de rede

Tags: php, diretório

Boa Tarde,
Estou usando o código abaixo para abrir uma pasta pela rede:

```
$dir = "\\\SR9\Infraestrutura\Controles\Termos\A\\" ;

$pasta = opendir($dir);

echo "<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='false' data-filter='true'>";   
echo("<li data-role='list-divider'><a href='#'>A</a></li>"); 

while ($arquivo = readdir($pasta)){
    if ($arquivo != '.' && $arquivo != '..'){
        echo "<li><a href='".$dir.$arquivo."' rel='external' >".$arquivo."</a></li>";
        }
}
```

O código acima serve para listar os diretórios. Está funcionando perfeitamente. Porem, quando eu clico no link, ele apresenta um erro 404.

> The requested URL /termos/\SR9\Controles\Termos\A\MEUARQUIVO.pdf was
>   not found on this server.

Como resolver?

Comment: acessar arquivos pela URL: tem que ter a barra para direita que eu saiba. Pois não tem como acessar a rede pelo navegador. E tem que ter um endereçamento tipo: `http://localhost/arquivos/seuarquivo.pdf` mas se você estiver listando diretórios pelo navegador, tente isso: `\\\SR9/Infraestrutura/Controles/Termos/A/seu_arquivo.pdf`

Comment: Isso se for a partir de um servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido retirando uma barra no inicio, que fazia com que o sistema não encontrasse o arquivo.

```
$dir = "\\SR9\Infraestrutura\Controles\Termos\A\\" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Por rede você não vai conseguir, mas acredito que se você fizer isso, possa dar certo, se você estiver listando diretórios através do navegador a partir de um servidor:

```
$dir = "\\\SR9/Infraestrutura/Controles/Termos/A/" ;
```